# Need to update HP via setHP in a Method in main-class (use non main-class method (setHP) in main-class method)

Tags: java, object, methods

So I am creating a small text based RPG and at the moment I'm trying to implement an HPUpdate into a method.

Because the methods in the main class can't access the getters and setters from the Object-Class, I needed to find a different solution.

I found one, don't know if it's correct, but it only seems to update the HP once, after that it always repeats the same HPUPdate.

"Goblin loses 10 HP!"
"Goblin has 40HP remaining!"

after attacking again, it's the same.

So not 30HP remaining, but 40HP again.

I made a second main class, where it worked, without using a Method. But I want to do it in a method.

Here's the code:

```java
Characters Fiona = new Characters(100, 10, 50, "Fiona"); // PLAYER CHARACTER INIT, FIONA = TEMP NAME
        Enemies Goblin = new Enemies(50, 10, 10, "Goblin"); // GOBLIN ENEMY INIT
```

```java
battlesystem(Fiona.getSpd(), Goblin.getSpd(), Fiona.getName(), Goblin.getName(), Fiona.getDmg(),
                Goblin.getDmg(), Fiona.setHp(setHPChar(Fiona.getHp(), Goblin.getDmg())),
                Goblin.setHp(setHPEnem(Goblin.getHp(), Fiona.getDmg())), Fiona.Statstostring(), Goblin.Statstostring());

    }

    // BATTLE_SYSTEM --> WIP
    public static int battlesystem(int playerspeed, int enemyspeed, String playername, String enemyname, int enemyDMG,
            int playerDMG, int playerHPUpdate, int enemyHPUpdate, String playerstats, String enemystats) {

        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        int newplayerhp = 0;
        System.out.printf(" Battle start! %n"); // Begin Battle-Scenario
        if (playerspeed <= enemyspeed) {
            System.out.printf(" Goblin attacks! %n");
            System.out.printf(" You lose %d HP! %n", enemyDMG);
            System.out.printf(" You have %d HP left!%n", playerHPUpdate);
        } else {

            System.out.printf(" %n What is your Strategy? %n");
            int i = 0;
            while (i < 1) {
                System.out.printf(" %n%n (A)ttack %n (D)efend %n (I)tems %n (S)tats %n (F)lee %n");
                String choice = sc1.nextLine();
                switch (choice.toUpperCase()) {
                case "A":
                    System.out.printf(" You decide to attack the Goblin! %n");
                    System.out.printf(" %S attacks!", playername);
                    System.out.printf(" %S loses %d HP%n", enemyname, enemyDMG);
                    System.out.printf(" Goblin has %d HP left!%n", enemyHPUpdate);

                    break;
```

EDIT:

Here's the UpdateHP-Method:

```
public static int setHPChar(int oldcharHP, int enemDMG) { // UPDATE Character HP through subtraction of the Enemy
                                                            // Damage

    int updateCharHP = oldcharHP - enemDMG; // setHP = getHP - getDMG
    return updateCharHP;

}

public static int setHPEnem(int oldenemHP, int charDMG) { // // UPDATE Enemy HP through subtraction of the Character
                                                            // Damage

    int updateEnemHP = oldenemHP - charDMG; // setHP = getHP - getDMG
    return updateEnemHP;
}
```

Here's the object class:

```
    private int hp; // Health Points STAT OF OBJECT
    private int dmg; // Damage Points STAT OF OBJECT
    private int spd; // Speed Points STAT OF OBJECT
    private String name; // Name OF OBJECT
    private boolean haskey = false; // BOOLEAN if OBJECT HAS A KEY --> only used in first    Scenario at the moment

    public int getHp() { // PRINTS Health Points of Character

        return hp;
    }

    public int setHp(int hp) { // INCREASES OR DECREASES Character Health Points
        this.hp = hp;
        return hp;
    }
```

So to recap, Character attacks Enemy, Enemy loses HP through Characters DMG.

EnemyHP - CharacterDMG = newEnemyHP.

Comment: Your whole program structure looks like it may be off. You shouldn't be passing player and enemy object *properties* into any method that needs to interact with these objects directly. Instead, pass the player and enemy objects themselves. But having said this, you shouldn't even being having to do this. Those objects should be passed into the Game object via a constructor or setter method, and then they should be free to interact with each other within the Game object. Re-think your structure.

Comment: As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Learning this and following this will allow us to better understand your code, and would allow you to better understand the code of others.

Comment: *"Because the methods in the main class can't access the getters and setters from the Object-Class, I needed to find a different solution."* -- and this is your problem. The main or Game class, *should* be able to call these methods. Don't try to fix poor program design with a kludge.  Again, re-think your program structure. I have to wonder though if this question is a poor fit for this site as it is quite broad.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels, thanks for the reminder about the naming in Java. I was so busy with ideas for the program that I overlooked the variable names. I am also thinking about the re-structure, so thank you for your comment!